# Want to create an array with unique elements

Tags: reactjs

create unique element array from an array, my array is like,

```
let arr=[{id:1, name:'tert'},{id:2, name:'tety'},{id:3, name:'gfvc'},{id:8, name:'tert'}]
```

I want an array like, `arrrslt= [{ name:'tert'},{name:'tety'}, {name:'gfvc'}]`.
How to create this type of array with unique elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to get the required properties and later apply `filter` over it to get the unique elements.

```
let seen = {};
const newArr = arr.map(a => ({ a.name })).filter(item => 
    seen.hasOwnProperty(item.name) ? false : (seen[item.name] = true)
);
```

Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=12&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjC8BtA3gSwCYC4CMAaCAdlALYiYDkYIMY5AvrmlgEz5GkVVgCe9jGmAMxsSZcgHMAZgDcAxnyaYAHCI6VqtOgF0A3ACg9qAlRiSoskIRAB3AIJwo3ACrcADpeR6IhUREwQAZzAYI3F9On09UEgAkBACCHgIZAi9WQB7AiCrOzhE6DgAOmIoVwAKKESAPggy5B8OaEL2SzpoAJz7GEcXdwBKPsLJVGATMtQqYmqIL29AuIJCgAsoAIB5awIABRh09xpuccnm0T6IAH4IM2BYv1rY+MQJkGIT0i184IBXED69PsiGSy6VAhWA6XEZQINi6AKAA) Typescript playground

Comment: getting error on this syntax

Comment: @LeyaVarghese - I've corrected the syntax which has an extra bracket. Please check the output at mentioned ts playground.

Answer (score 1):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const myTransform = arr => (  // method to transform (by removing dupes)
  Object.values(              // extract only values from below intermediate result obj
    arr.reduce(               // iterate using ".reduce()" over given array
      (acc, {name}) => (      // "acc" is the accumulator, destructure "name" from iterator
        acc[name] ??= {name},   // conditionally assign value to "acc[name]"
        acc                     // return "acc" on each iteration  
      ),
      {}                      // initialize "acc" as an empty object
    )                         // implicit return of "acc" object
  )                           // implicit return of "values" array from the above object
);

const myArr=[{id:1, name:'tert'},{id:2, name:'tety'},{id:3, name:'gfvc'},{id:8, name:'tert'}];

console.log('removed dupes...', myTransform(myArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

The Set object allows you to remove duplicates :

```
const getUnique = (array) => [...new Set(array.map(elem => ({name: elem['name']})))]
```

Cheers